# Using LINQ to group and count occurrences from dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Say I have a `Dictionary<int, String>` with following set of data :

```
1 a
2 a
3 a
4 b
5 b
6 b
7 b
8 c
9 c
10 c
```

I have 150 objects containing this Dictionary. Each object has different set of these data. In key-value pairs keys are always 1-10 and values might be one of this set {a,b,c}. 
I would like to use LINQ to Group these data and count occurrences of values (a,b,c) in the following way. In loop (`for`) :

```
1st iteration : group 1 (a)
2nd iteration : group 1 (a) (a)
3rd iteration : group 1 (a) (a) (a)
4th iteration : group 1 (a) (a) (a) 
                group 2 (b)
5th iteration : group 1 (a) (a) (a) 
                group 2 (b) (b)
6th iteration : group 1 (a) (a) (a) 
                group 2 (b) (b) (b)
7th iteration : group 1 (a) (a) (a) 
                group 2 (b) (b) (b) (b)
8th iteration : group 1 (a) (a) (a) 
                group 2 (b) (b) (b) (b)
                group 3 (c)
9th iteration : group 1 (a) (a) (a) 
                group 2 (b) (b) (b) (b) 
                group 3 (c) (c)
10th iteration : group 1 (a) (a) (a) 
                 group 2 (b) (b) (b) (b) 
                 group 3 (c) (c) (c)
```

So groups are created depending on the occurrences of the values. 
In 4th interation I have 2 groups created (a count = 3, b count = 1). In 8th iteration I have 3 groups created (a count = 3, b count = 4, c count = 1).

Further I would like to compare these occurrences and see which count dominates. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

### EDIT

Thank you for your quick answer but it doesn't apply for me. I wasn't sufficiently precise, I haven't explained it properly.

Iterations in the for loop depict specific `K` number in KNN algorithm. So I'm trying to implement KNN algorithm for K = 1, K = 2 ... K = 10. It's my idea to analyse groups of values (labels a,b,c) for a specific K. For a given `K` I need to know how many items do I have in each group to properly classify object containing `Dictionary<int, String>` but only for specific number of element (`K`) - not for all of them at once. For `K = 1` I take into account only first `KeyValuePair` in my Dictionary. For `K = 7` I take into account only 7 first `KeyValuePair` in my Dictionary and so on. Based on this I would like to compare each `Count` values of specific `K` which would help me to classify each object to specific label (a,b or c). I think I need use `for` loop to achieve this. But I don't know how.

So simple `var result = myDict.GroupBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());` will give a groups based on values (labels a,b,c) but all them at once.

I hope I havne't complicated things completely ...

Comment: What are you not storing a `Dictionary<string, int>` where the key is your label and the value is your count?

Comment: One of the great features of LINQ is that you can ommit all those looping and iterations and let do LINQ this for you. So why do you want to iterate your dictionary at all?

Comment: I'm confused, do you want a Linq query to get the final result or a for loop to get all the intermediate results as well?  Also what have you tried and what issues did you have with your attempt?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov - because I wanted Key (int) in my Dictionary to be K-number in KNN algorithm and value as label.

Answer (score 10):

With LINQ it is as simple as:

```
var result = myDict.GroupBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

You won´t need any iteration as LINQ is doing all the job for you.

To get the highest amount you may now simply call:

```
result.Max(x => x.Value);
```

Or if you also need the entry with that amount:

```
result.OrderBy(x => x.Value).First();
```